# utf-8 filename in s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

Is it possible to add a key to s3 with an utf-8 encoded name like "åøæ.jpg"?

I'm getting the following error when uploading with boto:

```
<Error><Code>InvalidURI</Code><Message>Couldn't parse the specified URI.</Message>
```

Answer (score 5):

@2083: This is a bit of an old question, but if you haven't found the solution, and for everyone else that comes here like me looking for an answer:

From the official documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html):

> Although you can use any UTF-8 characters in an object key name, the
>   following key naming best practices help ensure maximum compatibility
>   with other applications.  Each application may parse special
>   characters differently. The following guidelines help you maximize
>   compliance with DNS, web safe characters, XML parsers, and other APIs.
>
> Safe Characters
>
> The following character sets are generally safe for use in key names:
>
> Alphanumeric characters [0-9a-zA-Z]
>
> Special characters !, -, _, ., *, ', (, and )
>
> The following are examples of valid object key names:
>
> 4my-organization
>
> my.great_photos-2014/jan/myvacation.jpg
>
> videos/2014/birthday/video1.wmv

**However**, if what you really want, like me, is a **filename** that allows UTF-8 characters (note that this can be different from the key name). You have a way to do it!

From http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2591-embedding-foreign-characters-in-your-content-disposition-filename-header.htm and http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2696-overriding-content-type-and-content-disposition-headers-in-amazon-s3-pre-signed-urls.htm (Kudos to Ben Nadal) you can do that by making sure that when downloading the file, S3 will override the **Content-Disposition** header.

As I have done it in java, I include here the code, I'm sure you'll be able to easily translate it to Python :) :

```
      AmazonS3 s3 = S3Controller.getS3Client();

        //as per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

        String key = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("-")).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9._]", "");
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(
                S3Controller.bucketNameForBucket(S3Controller.Bucket.EXPORT_BUCKET), 
                key,
                file);
        // we can always regenerate these files, so we can used reduced redundancy storage
        putObjectRequest.setStorageClass(StorageClass.Standard);
        String urlEncodedUTF8Filename = key;
        try {
            //http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2696-overriding-content-type-and-content-disposition-headers-in-amazon-s3-pre-signed-urls.htm
            //http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2591-embedding-foreign-characters-in-your-content-disposition-filename-header.htm
            //Issue#179
            urlEncodedUTF8Filename = URLEncoder.encode(fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("-")), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            LOG.warn("Could not URLEncode a filename. Original Filename: " + fileName, e );
        }

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentDisposition("attachment; filename=\"" + key + "\"; filename*=UTF-8''"+ urlEncodedUTF8Filename);
        putObjectRequest.setMetadata(metadata);

        s3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

It should help :)

Comment: I got signature failure validations because the filename in content disposition and I were using PHP SDK (v3), but the content disposition is defined by me and not corrected by the SDK. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From AWS FAQ:
A key is a sequence of Unicode characters whose UTF-8 encoding is at most 1024 bytes long.

From my experience, use ASCII.