# AWS CLI Get objects urls non english characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get the public URLs for all the objects in my bucket. The hard thing is that object's names in my bucket are in cyrilic and consist of special characters as well. Could you please help?

Comment: Looks like this might have been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074800/utf-8-filename-in-s3-bucket/32340117.  TLDR seems to be that utf8 character support is difficult at best.

Comment: `S3 will override the Content-Disposition header` makes me think of Cloudfront + Lambda@Edge, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to output the E-tag of each item and its asscociated link with following command:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket <YOUR BUCKET> --encoding-type url --output table
```

this will output everything in a table